# Returning when multiple observables have finished - Angular2

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

I am trying to chain two actions that need to be performed right after each other as follows:

```
public main(data) {

    // A. 
    return this.methodA(data)
    .map(resA => {
      if (resA.hasOwnProperty('id')) {

        console.log('gets triggered');

        // B. 
        return this.methodB(resA).map(resB => {

          console.log('does not get triggered', resB)
          return resB.json();
        })

      } else {
        return resA;
      }
    })

}
```

Problem is that the second method does not get triggered. It only returns to me the observable and **not** the result from the observable (resB). How can this be overcome?

I am happy to do it also with promises, but I am not sure how that would work?

Comment: You have to subscribe on methodB to get trigger.

Comment: @Igor. Yes, but I want to use it as a service. Thus in another class I want to subscribe on the function main(data) instead of methodB.

Comment: Looks like you want to use the flatMap operator. Here is an example of how to use it: https://namitamalik.github.io/Map-vs-FlatMap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

```
public main(data) {

    return Observable.create(observer => {
        this.methodA(data).subscribe(resA => {
            if (resA.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
                this.methodB(resA).subscribe(resB =>{
                    observer.next(resB);
                })
            } else {
                observer.next(resA);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

And then you have to subscribe on method **main**